# is there any way to convert nested object to array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this

```js
const input = {
  id: 1,
  name: "nameOne",
  parent: {
    id: 2,
    name: "nameTwo",
    parent: { id: 3, name: "nameThree", parent: null },
  },
};
```

And want to convert it to an array like this

```js
const output = [
  { id: 1, name: "nameOne" },
  { id: 2, name: "nameTwo" },
  { id: 3, name: "nameThree" },
];
```

is there any way to do that?

Comment: yes, recursively process the object creating the output as you go

Comment: `function processObject(o) {
  const output = [];
  while(o) {
    const {id, name, parent} = o;
    output.push({id, name});
    o = parent;
  }
  return output;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achive this result using `recursion`.

```js
const input = {
  id: 1,
  name: "nameOne",
  parent: {
    id: 2,
    name: "nameTwo",
    parent: {
      id: 3,
      name: "nameThree",
      parent: null
    },
  },
};

function getResult(obj) {
  if (!obj) return;

  const { parent, ...rest } = obj;
  result.push({ ...rest });
  getResult(parent);
}

const result = [];
getResult(input);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this is useful but here's a weird way to achieve it:

```js
const input = {
  id: 1,
  name: "nameOne",
  parent: {
    id: 2,
    name: "nameTwo",
    parent: { id: 3, name: "nameThree", parent: null },
  },
};


const result = [...function*(input) {
  do yield { id: input.id, name: input.name }
  while(input = input.parent)
}(input)];

console.log(result);
```

---

### Explanation

What it does is not using a recursive function, but creating a generator IIFE, and spread it into an array, syntax:

```js
[...function*(){ /* code here */ }()]
```

Inside the generator there's a do while loop, since there's only one line for the loop body, the body curly braces are emitted, full syntax:

```js
do {
  yield { id: input.id, name: input.name }
} while(input = input.parent)
```

First it yields one object containing the `id` and `name` property from `input`(assuming the parameter object `input` has at least one layer). Then it assigns `input.parent` to `input` to prepare the next iteration: `while(input = input.parent)`.

If the expression evaluates thuthy, means there is another layer, so the loop body excutes again and produce the next object for the array, otherwise the function terminates and seals the generator function.

---

*This approach may look shorter but is not very practical and hard to understand, not recommended for real life projects.*